# Why the following norm is necessarily the Euclidean norm?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $N$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $N^2 : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_+, \ x \mapsto N^2(x)$ which is $\mathcal{C}^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $N$ must be the Euclidean norm (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\Vert x \Vert_2 = \displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x_k, x_k\rangle\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$).

I tried to exploit the hypothesis on the map $N^2$. Using Taylor-Young expansion formula for all $x, h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we get that : $N^2(x+h)= N^2(x)+ \mathrm dN^2(x)(h) + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm d^2N^2(x)(h)^2 + o(\Vert h\Vert_\infty^2)$.

Trying to follow the hint given in the comments :

For $x=0$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can write : $N^2(h) = \underbrace{N^2(0)}_{= \ 0} + \underbrace{\mathrm dN^2(0)(h)}_{= \ 0 \ \text{by a min argument}} + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}^2N^2(0)(h)^2 + o(\Vert h\Vert_\infty^2)$.

Also for all $t\in \mathbb{R}^*$, $N^2(h)=\dfrac{N^2(th)}{t^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}^2N^2(0)(h)^2 + o(\Vert h\Vert_\infty^2)$. But then how can I get rid of $o(\Vert h \Vert_infty^2)$ ? I will be perfect if it becomes a $o(1)$. To conclude I will take $t \to 0$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Need to use homogeneity. $N(tx) = tN(x)$.

Comment: @Maman you can set $t:=\|h\|$ and now write the Taylor expansion using this, then you will have $h=t \hat h$ where $\hat h:=h/\|h\|$ when $h\neq 0$

Comment: @Masacroso with your substitution I have finally a : $o(t^2)=t^2 o(1)$ (by definition). Hence taking $t \to 0$, I get that $N^2(h) = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathrm d^2 N^2(0) (h)^2$ which represents a quadratic form !

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your notation, but your hypotheses seem to be that $N$ is a norm and $x \mapsto (N(x))^2$ is $C^2$. This is far to weak to guarantee that $N$ is euclidean. E.g., $N$ could be the $L_p$ norm for some $p$ with $2 < p < \infty$.

Comment: Yes, $L_p$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if $p \geq 2$ (but $p \neq \infty$) then $L_p^2$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: @aschepler by the $L_p$ norm you were thinking about $L_p(x)= \displaystyle \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert x_k \vert^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ with $+\infty >p \ge 2$ ?

Comment: You do not mention what the $x_k$ are. I guess the elements of a basis of $E$. But where does the inner product $\langle x_k, x_k \rangle$ come from? Do you mean that a Euclidean space is one with an inner product? If so, then $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$.

Comment: I am sorry but your question makes no sense to me. To say $E$ is isometric to some $\Bbb{R}^n$ implies that you have fixed the norm on $E$, so what is this other norm $N$?

Comment: The Euclidean norm on $(E, \langle\ ,\ \rangle)$ is nothing else than $\Vert x \Vert= \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$. Again: What are the vectors $x_k$? They must somehow depend on $x$. Where does the question come from?

Comment: @aschepler do you have a proof that the square of the norm $L_p$ for $p\in (2, +\infty)$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? I mean if the square of the norm is $L_p^2(x) = \displaystyle \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \vert x_k \vert^p \right)^\frac{2}{p}$.